# How to reference webform field option?

Tags: 8, webforms

So I have webform module installed and I created a webform. Webform has an choice field (drop-down). Let's say you can select one of 3 options: "one", "two", "three". I need a way to add (editable) array of numbers to each of this option. I.e.

one:  75, 50, 80

two:  25, 50, 65

three: 20, 40, 70

So, as far as I know those options are not entities and I can not add fields to them to store those numbers.

My idea is to create new content type to hold those numbers, but I need a way to connect field options with my new content type. Meaning, when creating new node in that new content type, beside entering numbers 75, 50, 80 I need a reference field with options "one", "two" and "three" so I could know to what webform field numbers in this node belong.

Other way would be to reference other way - to add node reference to field option, but I think that's not possible either.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'd rather use the "Entity select" input field (or similiar) for this - allows direct selection of a referenced entities, optionally filtered by custom view.

Comment: Ok, but where should I put that entity select field? Field option is not entity so I can't add that field inside my content type. And I can't add reference to new content type inside option since it's not entity again.

Comment: Just for clarification: Your users shall submit webforms, and when they do so they also shall select some options based on previously created content nodes?

Comment: No, they will see only drop-down with those 3 values: "one", "two", "three" and can select one of them. And then in my custom submission handler I'll check what user selected and if he selected i.e. "one" I want to read values 75,50,80...and if he selected "two" I want to read 25,50,65... for my internal processing. User will not be aware of those numbers at all.

Comment: So basically with every field option I need some extra (editable) data, some array of numbers, visible only from form submission handler.

Comment: Why not using simple dropdown/select inputs? Every HTML select input field has a label (visible to users, e.g. "one", "two",...) and a value (e.g. "25,50,70", "1,2,3",...). The value string can be transformed to an array of numbers using `explode` if you need to do post processing.

Comment: Because those numbers should be also edited by admins. There's actually more of 10 numbers and would be nightmare to edit them correctly. That's why I wanted to create new content type for entering them - so I can have separate field with appropriate title for each number. So that would work, but not appropriate for my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97582/discussion-between-hudri-and-milang).